# Two different advertisement position depends on content height

Tags: jquery, html, css

```css
#scrollarea {
    overflow:hidden
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom:1
}

.clearfix: before,.clearfix: after {
    display:table;
    content:""
}

.clearfix: after {
    clear:both
}

.hide - text {
    font:0 / 0 a;
    color:transparent;
    text-shadow:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:0
}

.input - block - level {
    display:block;
    width:100px %;
    min-height:28px px;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border - box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border - box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border - box;
    box-sizing:border - box
}

.hidden {
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden
}

.visible - phone {
    display:none!important
}

.visible - tablet {
    display:none!important
}

.hidden - desktop {
    display:none!important
}

@
media(max - width: 767 px) {
    .visible-phonedisplay:inherit!important
}

.hidden - phone {
    display:none!important
}

.hidden - desktop {
    display:inherit!important
}

.visible - desktop {
    display:none!important
}
}

@
media(min - width: 768 px) and(max - width: 979 px) {
    .visible-tabletdisplay:inherit!important
}

.hidden - tablet {
    display:none!important
}

.hidden - desktop {
    display:inherit!important
}

.visible - desktop {
    display:none!important
}
}

@
media(max - width: 480 px) {
    .nav-collapse-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)
}

.page - header h1 small {
    display:block;
    line-height:18 px
}
}

@
media(max - width: 767 px) {
    bodypadding-right:20 px;
    padding-left:20px px
}

.navbar - fixed - top,.navbar - fixed - bottom {
    margin-right:-20px px;
    margin-left:-20px px
}

.container - fluid {
    padding:0
}

.dl - horizontal dt {
    float:none;
    width:auto;
    clear:none;
    text-align:left
}

.dl - horizontal dd {
    margin-left:0
}

.container {
    width:auto
}

.row - fluid {
    width:100px %
}
}

@
media(min - width: 768 px) and(max - width: 979 px) {
    .rowmargin-left:-20 px;
    *zoom:1
}

.row: before,.row: after {
    display:table;
    content:""
}

.row: after {
    clear:both
}

[class *= span] {
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px px
}

.container,.navbar - fixed - top.container,.navbar - fixed - bottom.container {
    width:724px px
}

.span12 {
    width:724px px
}

.span11 {
    width:662px px
}

.span10 {
    width:600px px
}

.span9 {
    width:538px px
}

.span8 {
    width:476px px
}

.span7 {
    width:414px px
}

.span6 {
    width:352px px
}

.span5 {
    width:290px px
}

.span4 {
    width:228px px
}

.span3 {
    width:166px px
}

.span2 {
    width:104px px
}

.span1 {
    width:42px px
}

.row - fluid {
    width:100px %;
    *zoom:1
}

.row - fluid: before,.row - fluid: after {
    display:table;
    content:""
}

.row - fluid: after {
    clear:both
}

.row - fluid[class *= span] {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:100px %;
    min-height:28px px;
    margin-left:2.762430939px %;
    *margin-left:2.7092394496383 %;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border - box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border - box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border - box;
    box-sizing:border - box
}

.row - fluid[class *= span]: first - child {
    margin-left:0
}

.row - fluid.span12 {
    width:99.999999993px %;
    *width:99.946808503638 %
}

.row - fluid.span11 {
    width:91.436464082px %;
    *width:91.383272592638 %
}

.row - fluid.span10 {
    width:82.872928171px %;
    *width:82.819736681638 %
}

.row - fluid.span9 {
    width:74.30939226px %;
    *width:74.256200770638 %
}

.row - fluid.span8 {
    width:65.745856349px %;
    *width:65.692664859638 %
}

.row - fluid.span7 {
    width:57.182320438px %;
    *width:57.129128948638 %
}

.row - fluid.span6 {
    width:48.618784527px %;
    *width:48.565593037638 %
}

.row - fluid.span5 {
    width:40.055248616px %;
    *width:40.002057126638 %
}

.row - fluid.span4 {
    width:31.491712705px %;
    *width:31.438521215638 %
}

.row - fluid.span3 {
    width:22.928176794px %;
    *width:22.874985304638 %
}

.row - fluid.span2 {
    width:14.364640883px %;
    *width:14.311449393638 %
}

.row - fluid.span1 {
    width:5.801104972px %;
    *width:5.7479134826383 %
}
}

@
media(min - width: 1200 px) {
    .rowmargin-left:-30 px;
    *zoom:1
}

.row: before,.row: after {
    display:table;
    content:""
}

.row: after {
    clear:both
}

[class *= span] {
    float:left;
    margin-left:30px px
}

.container,.navbar - fixed - top.container,.navbar - fixed - bottom.container {
    width:1170px px
}

.span12 {
    width:1170px px
}

.span11 {
    width:1070px px
}

.span10 {
    width:970px px
}

.span9 {
    width:870px px
}

.span8 {
    width:770px px
}

.span7 {
    width:670px px
}

.span6 {
    width:570px px
}

.span5 {
    width:470px px
}

.span4 {
    width:370px px
}

.span3 {
    width:270px px
}

.span2 {
    width:170px px
}

.span1 {
    width:70px px
}

.row - fluid {
    width:100px %;
    *zoom:1
}

.row - fluid: before,.row - fluid: after {
    display:table;
    content:""
}

.row - fluid: after {
    clear:both
}

.row - fluid[class *= span] {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:100px %;
    min-height:28px px;
    margin-left:2.564102564px %;
    *margin-left:2.5109110746383 %;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border - box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border - box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border - box;
    box-sizing:border - box
}

.row - fluid[class *= span]: first - child {
    margin-left:0
}

.row - fluid.span12 {
    width:100px %;
    *width:99.946808510638 %
}

.row - fluid.span11 {
    width:91.452991453px %;
    *width:91.399799963638 %
}

.row - fluid.span10 {
    width:82.905982906px %;
    *width:82.852791416638 %
}

.row - fluid.span9 {
    width:74.358974359px %;
    *width:74.305782869638 %
}

.row - fluid.span8 {
    width:65.811965812px %;
    *width:65.758774322638 %
}

.row - fluid.span7 {
    width:57.264957265px %;
    *width:57.211765775638 %
}

.row - fluid.span6 {
    width:48.717948718px %;
    *width:48.664757228638 %
}

.row - fluid.span5 {
    width:40.170940171px %;
    *width:40.117748681638 %
}

.row - fluid.span4 {
    width:31.623931624px %;
    *width:31.570740134638 %
}

.row - fluid.span3 {
    width:23.076923077px %;
    *width:23.023731587638 %
}

.row - fluid.span2 {
    width:14.52991453px %;
    *width:14.476723040638 %
}

.row - fluid.span1 {
    width:5.982905983px %;
    *width:5.9297144936383 %
}

.row - fluid.thumbnails {
    margin-left:0
}
}

@
media(max - width: 979 px) {
    bodypadding-top:0
}

.nav - collapse.nav > li > a: hover,.nav - collapse.dropdown - menu a: hover {
    background-color:#222
}

.nav-collapse.in .btn-group {
    padding:0;
    margin-top:5px
}

.nav-collapse .dropdown-menu {
    position:static;
    top:auto;
    left:auto;
    display:block;
    float:none;
    max-width:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 15px;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:0;
    -webkit-border-radius:0;
    -moz-border-radius:0;
    border-radius:0;
    -webkit-box-shadow:none;
    -moz-box-shadow:none;
    box-shadow:none
}

.nav-collapse .dropdown-menu:before,.nav-collapse .dropdown-menu:after {
    display:none
}

.nav-collapse .dropdown-menu .divider {
    display:none
}

.nav-collapse .navbar-form,.nav-collapse .navbar-search {
    float:none;
    padding:9px 15px;
    margin:9px 0;
    border-top:1px solid # 222px;
    border-bottom:1px px solid #222;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1),0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1),0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1),0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1)
}

.navbar .nav-collapse .nav.pull-right {
    float:none;
    margin-left:0
}

.nav-collapse,.nav-collapse.collapse {
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden
}

.navbar .btn-navbar {
    display:block
}

.navbar-static .navbar-inner {
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:10px
}
}

@media(min-width:980px) {
.nav-collapse.collapse {
    height:auto!important;
    overflow:visible!important
}

.span6 img {
    position:absolute;
    width:auto!important;
    margin-top:180px
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=500, initial-scale=1">
            <title>Harvey - CSS media query state management</title>
            <link href="style.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->
        </head>
        <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".subnav" data-offset="50">
            <div class="container">
                <section id="whatitis">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h1>Why do I Need Harvey? </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span6">
                            <h3>A state manager for CSS media queries</h3>
                            <div id="scrollarea">Media queries are great for visual tweaks and simple 
                                behavioral switches, but they become difficult to rely on when behaviors
                                change for larger or smaller devices. Harvey helps you monitor and 
                                manage those changes by firing an event whenever your media query is 
                                activated.
                                This method is preferable to relying on a screen resize 
                                event because you only receive an event when the query is matched -- not
                                for every screen resize. Less testing and more doing.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="span6">          
                            <img style="width:100%; height:auto; border:none;" src="728x90.png">          
                        </div>
                        <div class="span6">
                            <h3>A state manager for CSS media queries</h3>
                            <p>Media queries are great for visual tweaks and simple 
                                behavioral switches, but they become difficult to rely on when behaviors
                                change for larger or smaller devices. Harvey helps you monitor and 
                                manage those changes by firing an event whenever your media query is 
                                activated.
                            </p>
                            <p>This method is preferable to relying on a screen resize 
                                event because you only receive an event when the query is matched -- not
                                for every screen resize. Less testing and more doing.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

`I need two different advertisement positions depends upon the dynamic article content height.

1. Vertical middle position of the advertisement between the content (If the content full on window height - see below sample layout)

[image]

2. Content bottom position of the advertisement (If the content few lines on window height - see below sample layout)

[image]
Any possible solutions to accomplish this precise behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your article is structured in paragraphs, you could use jQuery (or better: plain Javascript) to move the ad after the first or second paragraph. This will, of course, not ensure that the ad sits exactly in the vertical middle, but may be what you want.

I've put up a jsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/v5o0pj6t/1/

```
var vArticleHeight = document.getElementById("divArticle").scrollHeight;

if(vArticleHeight > (window.innerHeight - 100)) { //subtract 100 to accomodate the ad
    var vParagraphs = document.getElementById("divArticle").querySelectorAll("p"); //get all paragraphs
    var vParagraph;

    //loop through the paragraphs
    for (vIndex in vParagraphs) {
        vParagraph = vParagraphs[vIndex];
        //for each paragraph, look if it starts below 50% of the window
        if((vParagraph.offsetTop / window.innerHeight) > 0.5) {
            //if it does, then insert the ad before
            vParagraph.parentNode.insertBefore(document.getElementById("divAd"), vParagraph);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. but I am getting this error " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null". Kindly help me....

Comment: How to implement margin/position instead of insertBefore. Thanks for advance.

Comment: jsFiddle executes the Javascript code onLoad. To achieve this in your script, you need to put the code inside a function and add it as an onLoad event handler `document.addEventListener("load", PlaceYourFunctionHereWithoutParentheses, false);` Then, scrollHeight shouldn't be null any more.

Comment: I would not suggest to follow a "margin/position" approach, because if you position your ad absolutely, it will appear above the article (the article will continue below the ad).

Comment: How to effect this above code on window resize. Thanks for advance.

Comment: `document.addEventListener("resize", PlaceYourFunctionHereWithoutParentheses, false);` If my answer helped you, please mark it as answer.

Comment: Fiddle: jsfiddle.net/gsk/45tz5mwr - Above the first sample working fine with this code, but second one not working properly. Thanks for Advance.